# Как сделать вычисление разницы (не равна 1 или -1 – то вернуть false.)

Tags: javascript

Функцию isJumping, которая принимает число и возвращает строку `JUMPING`, если каждая цифра в числе отличается от соседней на 1, а если нет — строка `NOT JUMPING`.
Как написать эту логику, помогите, совсем запутался.

```
function isJumping(number) {
  let toStr = String(number);
  let previusNum = toStr[0];
  let current;
  for (let i = 1; i < toStr.length; i++) {
    current = Number(toStr[i]);
    let count = Math.abs(current - previusNum);
    if(count === 1 || count -1){
      return false
    }
  }
  return true
}
```

Comment: Находить разницу двух соседних цифр и сравнивать с 1 и - 1. Вот и вся логика. Тебе нужно возвращать слова, а ты почему-то возвращаешь true или false. Ну и посмотри в каком случае что нужно возвращать. И на сравнение посмотри, ерунду какую-то там написал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в своем коде Вы забыли несколько моментов:

- Math.abs не может вернуть -1
- `count === 1 || count -1` - это условие сработает если count будет равен единице либо если count будет больше единицы ( `||count -1`)
- Выходить с false (`NOT JUMPING`) нужно только если разница не совпадает с 1
- Перенести текущее число в предыдущее чтобы цепочка не обрывалась

```js
function isJumping(number) {
  let toStr = String(number);
  let previusNum = toStr[0];
  let current;
  for (let i = 1; i < toStr.length; i++) {
    current = Number(toStr[i]);
    let count = Math.abs(current - previusNum);
    // count может быть только положительным
    // выход только если не 1
    if(count !== 1){ 
      return 'NOT JUMPING'
    }
    previusNum = current // переносим в previusNum
  }
  return 'JUMPING'
}

console.log(isJumping(13))    // NOT JUMPING
console.log(isJumping(123))   // JUMPING
console.log(isJumping(12321)) // JUMPING
console.log(isJumping(1235))  // NOT JUMPING
```

Со своей стороны я считаю что раз задачка математическая а не строковая то и решать ее нужно математическими средствами

```js
function isJumping(number) {
  let previusNum = number % 10
  number = Math.floor(number / 10) 
  while (number){
    current = number % 10
    number = Math.floor(number / 10) 
    if (Math.abs(current - previusNum) !== 1){
      return 'NOT JUMPING'
    }
    previusNum = current
  } 
  return 'JUMPING'
}

console.log(isJumping(13))    // NOT JUMPING
console.log(isJumping(123))   // JUMPING
console.log(isJumping(12321)) // JUMPING
console.log(isJumping(1235))  // NOT JUMPING
```

Comment: Большое спасибо что растолковали!!!

Comment: Пожалуйста, успехов в учебе и будьте внимательнее)